# Exchange a function and its arguments while maximizing

Tags: integration, optimization

I have a problem of the form:

$$
\max_{\{f(x)\}} \int_0^1 g(f(x)) dx
$$

where the notation ${\{f(x)\}}$ means "find a function $f(x)$ that maximizes this integral", and

$$
g(x) = (\alpha + x) f(x) + (1 - \alpha)\int_0^1 f(z) dz -\frac{f(x)^2}{2}
$$

The result should be $f(x) = 1 + x$.

My issue is that the integral is over $x$, while the maximization is over a function of $x$, i.e. the reverse of what you usually have when applying Leibniz's rule. This looks an awful lot like an optimal control problem to me, but I can't really  point my finger to what warrants "not solving it like an optimal control problem": this is a mandatory class in a program that offers a class in optimal control, which I took, but where said class is not mandatory - so we should be able to solve it without invoking optimal control.

How should I go about solving these kinds of problems in general? Just ignoring the integral and maximizing $g(x, y)$ as if $f(x) = y$ were an ordinary variable doesn't yield the result stated in the text of the problem.

The only way I have found to make this work is to drop the integral and find a first-order condition of the form

$$
(\alpha + x) + (1 - \alpha) = f(x)
$$

But I don't get then why, in a previous point, we are asked to maximize pointwise, i.e.

$$\max_{f(x)} g(f(x))$$

and the first-order condition then takes the form

$$
\alpha + x = f(x)
$$

i.e. the inner integral is ignored.

Comment: What is $g$ and what is the result stated in the text of the problem?

Comment: Added, sorry, I am still getting the hang of what is considered relevant and what isn't.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with *calculus of variations* but I think the idea is that you add a small spike at some $x_0$ to $f$ and if $f$ is a critical point then $0$ is a critical point of $g$ as a function of the height of the spike. But the change in $g$ due to the spike only depends on what happens near $x_0$, so if you take limits appropriately you get conditions in terms of $f(x_0)$ etc.